# select only date from yy-mm-dd hr-min-sec format in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datatables

I have a field **created_at** which is in the format *yy-mm-dd hr-min-sec*  .. now how to select only date part of this field?

```
function customers(){

    $this->datatables
    ->select('created_at')
    ->group_by('email')
    ->from('customers')

    echo $this->datatables->generate();
}
```

How to reg this stuff?

Comment: Where is the date field?

Comment: '$var='yy-mm-dd hr-min-sec'; $var=date('y-m-d', strtotime($var));`

Comment: sorry guys .. i have edited the code ... can u please look at it now

Answer (score 0):

Set the value from the created_at field to $result then

```
$date = new DateTime($result);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: I agree doing it in the PHP code is the way to go. DateTime is also more useful than substr() as in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in the query with the SUBSTRING command:

```
->select('SUBSTRING(created_at,1,8)')
```

(note the first character starts at index 1)

However it would be better performance-wise to do it in the resulting PHP code.

```
echo substr($data->created_at,0,8);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `DATE()` function and your query should look like

```
->select("DATE(`created_at`) AS created_at",FALSE) // to avoid additional bacticks
```

Answer (score 0):

Expecting you are using MYSQL

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/date-and-time-functions.html

```
function customers(){

        $this->datatables
        ->select('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y/%m/%d') as view_created_at')
        ->group_by('email')
        ->from('customers')

     echo $this->datatables->generate();

   }
```

thend you just need to do view_created_at;